# How can I compute the limit $\lim_{m \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^m \left(1 - \frac{x}{m}\right)^{k-1} \frac{x}{m}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am uncertain about how to compute this limit, because the terms of the sequence being summed here depend on the upper bound of the sum.

Suppose I define
$$F(M, m) := \sum_{k=1}^M \left(1 - \frac{x}{m}\right)^{k-1} \frac{x}{m}.$$
Then what I want is $\lim_{m \to \infty} F(m, m)$. I know that in general, the limit of $F$ can depend on the path taken, so that
$$\lim_{m \to \infty} F(m, m) \neq \lim_{M \to \infty} \lim_{m \to \infty} F(M, m)$$ in general. What conditions do I need on $F$ in order for the above to be true? In any case, clearly this is not true here since:
$$\lim_{M \to \infty} \lim_{m \to \infty} F(M, m) = 0$$
whereas
$$\lim_{m \to \infty} \lim_{M \to \infty} F(M, m) = 1.$$

Could I have a hint about how to calculate the above limit?

Comment: $$F(x,M,m)=\frac{x}{m}\frac{1-(1-\frac{x}{m})^M}{1-\big(1-\frac{x}{m}\big)}=1-(1-x/m)^M$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$F(M,m)=\frac{x}{m}\frac{1-(1-\frac{x}{m})^M}{1-\big(1-\frac{x}{m}\big)}=1-(1-x/m)^M$$

- If $m>x>0$, and $m$ fixed,  $\lim_{M\rightarrow\infty}F(x,M,m)=1$
- For $M$ fixed, $\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}F(x,M,m)=0$
- If $\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}F(x,m,m)=1-e^{-x}$